# Proving a result regarding a homogenous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am struggling with with a problem regarding a function $F(x,y)$ that satisfies the following condition:

$F(\phi x,\phi^{\alpha+\beta-1}y)=\phi^\beta F(x,y)$, for all $\phi, \alpha, \beta > 0$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are constants between 0 and 1.

It is stated that this condition implies that:

$F(x,y)=x^\beta f(x^{1-\alpha-\beta}y)$ for some function $f$.

Is see that the latter expression satisfies the condition, but I fail to prove the implication. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the domains/codomains of your functions?

Comment: Both functions have domain and codomain equal to the non-negative reals

Comment: Made an error in the LHS of the condition, it is now fixed. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that plugging in $x=1$ in the second equation suggests that we define $f(y) := F(1,y)$. Then, assuming the first equation holds, we have
$$ x^\beta f(x^{1-\alpha-\beta}y) = x^\beta F(1,x^{1-\alpha-\beta}y) = F(x\cdot1,x^{\alpha+\beta-1}\cdot  x^{1-\alpha-\beta}y) = F(x,y).$$

Comment: Thanks, Alex! That does it.